# Bootstrap left align text inside centered div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a paragraph of 4 lines that are poetry in a centered div. Because it is poetry, I need the 4 lines aligned left, but not to the left side of the div.

Here is how it is centered:

```
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        onsectetur adipisicin.
  Doloribus, totam unde facilis omnis 
        temporibus nostrum in
```

Here is how I want it:

```
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  onsectetur adipisicin.
  Doloribus, totam unde facilis omnis 
  temporibus nostrum in
```

Thanks.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YW7eS/)

Comment: can you provide your html and css?  perhaps create a jsfiddle?

Comment: does `text-align:left` not work for you?

Comment: text-align:left aligns it to the edge of the div. I need the text to stay the center of the div, just the lined aligned one under another.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/ I am using this template. The text in the middle of 3 messages is centered.

Comment: sorry that doesn't make any sense. If you want to indent it, use `margin-left: 100px;`

Comment: Sorry, I am uncertain how to explain this properly. The text is centered, therefore each line is centered. I want the line to be aligned with each other. I am also using <br> between lines. I will try and create jsfiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/YW7eS/2/

I removed text-align: center and used the grid system to give you more control.

```
<div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide any code its quite hard to help you, but this is (I guess) what you want. Change the left padding to whatever number to increase/decrease the distance of the text to the div.

```
.poetry {
   padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.poetry p {
   text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to show us the code, but you probably want to do `text-align:left` on the paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

just try something like this:

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; float: left;"></div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 30px;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  onsectetur adipisicin.
  Doloribus, totam unde facilis omnis 
  temporibus nostrum in
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the code like this,

```
.marketing .col-md-4 {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

see the working [fiddle](http://bootply.com/80616) here

Comment: Yes it aligns the lines just as I want, but at the same time  it aligns everything else inside that .marketing .col-md-4 to the left.

Comment: you just want to left align the <p> content?

Comment: can you use class "text-center" and "text-left", for DIV <div class="col-md-4 text-center"> and  <p class="text-left"> both are bootstrap class

Comment: But not the whole <p>, just so the the 3 lines of the paragraph aligned with the first line.

Comment: then put the content in a span  you want to align left

Comment: span does not help.  I removed bootsrap.css [Here is updated jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/YW7eS/1/). As you can see if I align <p> left, it moves all the way to the left of the parent container. How can I keep it centered but all 4 lines aligned?

Comment: Can't use fixed width. Bootsrap uses % for responsive... Thanks for your time!

Comment: u can use 30% as width