# Bootstrap left align text inside centered div stretched background color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

With reference to above post:

[Bootstrap left align text inside centered div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770044/bootstrap-left-align-text-inside-centered-div/32153840#32153840)

I want more modification into that... I want one background color strip for strip for each block. Currently it is coming only on content. As screen resizes it should extend as it is.

Following is code HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
    <table border="0" align="center" class="yellow col-sm-12">
        <tbody><tr>
        <td align="left"><strong>S.B.Road – Head Office</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">The Mesh, B29, Nilgiri Heights, Behind ICC Trade Tower, Senapati Bapat Road, Pune-411016.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">(Mobile): +91 99232 11122</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">(Email): <a href="mailto:deepti@themesh.co.in">deepti@themesh.co.in</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
</div><!--conaddress end-->
</row>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
    <table border="0" align="center" class="green">
        <tbody><tr>
        <td align="left"><strong>Baner</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">The Capital, B-301, Sr. No. 5/1A, Next to Nano Space IT Park & Rolling Hills, Baner-Pashan Link Road, Pune - 411021</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">(Mobile): +91 99232 11122</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">(Email): <a href="mailto:deepti@themesh.co.in">deepti@themesh.co.in</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
</div><!--conaddress end-->
</row>
```

Following is my CSS code

```
.yellow {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #FFB700;
}
.green{   padding-bottom: 10px; background-color:#99FFCC;}
```

Current Output: `http://wizdumb.in/current.jpg`
Expected Output: `http://wizdumb.in/expeceted-result.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

1. It dependes on which elment you put your ".yellow" and ".green" styles.
2. Problem might be in container class too. There are differences between [".container" and ".container-fluid"](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) classes.

Id do it as folowing: https://jsfiddle.net/6ur3n9vu/1/

```
 <section class="yellow">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
        <table border="0" align="center" class="yellow col-sm-12">
        <tbody><tr>
        <td align="left"><strong>S.B.Road – Head Office</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">The Mesh, B29, Nilgiri Heights, Behind ICC Trade Tower, Senapati Bapat Road, Pune-411016.</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">(Mobile): +91 99232 11122</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">(Email): <a href="mailto:deepti@themesh.co.in">deepti@themesh.co.in</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
       </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="green">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
        <table border="0" align="center" class="green">
        <tbody><tr>
        <td align="left"><strong>Baner</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">The Capital, B-301, Sr. No. 5/1A, Next to Nano Space IT Park & Rolling Hills, Baner-Pashan Link Road, Pune - 411021</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">(Mobile): +91 99232 11122</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">(Email): <a href="mailto:deepti@themesh.co.in">deepti@themesh.co.in</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Great help ...:)Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem, if that solves you problem accept it as answer ;)